# Remove difference of 2 images with GIMP

Tags: gimp, transparency, background

I have two images:

One with a white background
[image]

and one with a black background
[image]

How can I remove the difference and replace it with transparency using GIMP?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You don't need to do that. The image with the white background already has enough contrast to make a pretty good layer mask. [see example](https://imgur.com/9rG0FnA). And in any case, setting one layer to difference the other will mess up the word "studio", because they aren't the same colour.

Comment: @BillyKerr The red buttons aren't identical either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Difference blending mode to create a mask won't really work with these images, because the word "studio" is in black on one image, but white on the other. The word "Amazing" is also different in each image, and the red dot of the "i" isn't identical in both images either, as @xenoid points out in a comment.

I mean you could try it and see for yourself. Put the black background image above the white, and set the layer blending mode to difference. Create a new layer from visible, invert it, and copy and paste the result into a layer mask on the white background version, and anchor it. Delete the unwanted layers. But the mask will need considerable fixing.

In my opinion, you don't need to do any of that anyway. The image with the white background already has enough contrast to make a pretty good selection of the white background. My approach would be similar to xenoids answer, except that I'd probably use the selection to create layer mask - which gives you a little more leeway to fix things if the mask isn't quite right.

[image]

Comment: This has the opposite effect of what I want - The background is kept while the rest is replaced with transparency (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUv2p.png). How can I do the reverse?

Comment: @myself600 Yes, that's why I said you need to invert it. All you need to do is select the mask and do *Colors > Invert*. Or when creating a mask from a selection, there's an invert option in the Add Layer Mask dialog

Comment: After several attempts, I was finally able to do it: https://i.imgur.com/WjCMioV.png (I used "Colors -> Invert" and "Copy Visible"). However, there are still grey edges when displayed against a dark background (I expected it to be closer to original than when using the Wand tool). Regarding the edges, is there some other method outside using the Wand tool as suggested by @xenoid that would come close to what moving the opacity slider does on the Layers tab?

Comment: @myself600 - I've added another answer. Check it out

Comment: I've marked this as a direct answer to my question even tho it wasn't the optimal one, as that would be the combination of Wand threshold and "Grow selection". Thank you both BillyKerr and @xenoid for your input!

Answer (score 0):

My usual technique (applies to both):

- Wand-select the background
- Don't forget to include isolated areas (the two Aa of Amazing, the D and O, and four triangles in the logo), by shift-clicking in them to add them to the selection. Don't be clever and use color selection instead to avoid this.
- `Select > Grow` by one pixel so that the selection includes a one-pixel edge of the previously un-selected areas
- Set the bucket-fill tool to "Color erase" mode, and `Fill whole selection`

[image]

- Bucket-fill with the color to erase

Composite image of the results, over contrasting background to check the edges:

[image]

Comment: I usually do the same too with a minor difference: use the picture with black background as the edges would be less noticeable against light colors, use Wand tool with highest threshold possible that does not leak into the objects, hold Shift to select all the parts to remove, invert selection, select none, Ctrl+X, 2 steps back in history, Ctrl+C, latest history, Ctrl+V. The problem with this approach is that it's not perfect.

Comment: The "minor difference" is fundamental. With a plain selection, the pixels on edges are either fully selected or not selected, so you get a jagged edge (too much selection, or a rim of remnants (not enough selection) and there is no "just right" setting; The technique above is different, it transforms th epixels on the edge to partially opaque pixels so that they blend correctly in any background. See [this](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Background-removal-or-replacement-on-text-logos-and-other-computer-graphics) for more explantions.

Comment: The only difference is using "Grow selection" to catch the surrounding pixels that would otherwise not be made transparent and yes, it seems to solve the issue of grabbing all of the anti-aliased pixels. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No, the big difference it the `Color erase` painting...If you image has a strong contrast (says, black text on white) you don't even need the selection. The selection is only used to keep opaque areas of the subject that could have some erasable color.

Comment: Nothing happens when I bucket fill the background for some reason https://i.imgur.com/2OjQ50i.png https://i.imgur.com/NLaa9Ba.png - I've used "Color to Alpha" instead

Comment: You want to erase white, so you should bucket fill with white (your FG color is red)(also Tool options is the important thing to display in this case)

Comment: Tried #ffffff as FG color, same results: https://i.imgur.com/cLpJRLw.mp4. The "Tool options" should be the 2nd link in my previous comment.

Comment: Is there an alpha channel and is the selection on the background?

Comment: Adding an alpha channel fixed the issue, thanks! :thumbsup: https://i.imgur.com/9n0uVlU.png

Comment: Cool. So consider marking the question answered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method, this time to counter the problem of anti-aliased pixels in the mask leaving an outline of greyish pixels, and also keeping the anti-aliasing of the original intact so that the edges look smooth and not jagged.

1. Open the image with the white background, right click it in the layers panel, and choose *Add Alpha channel*. If this option is greyed out, there's already an alpha channel and you can skip this step.
2. Select all the white areas using the Fuzzy Select tool, including the insides of the letters A,a,D,O, and also not forgetting the 4 little white triangles in the logo. Holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click allows you to select multiple areas.
3. Do *Select > Grow*, by 1px
4. Do *Select > Invert*
5. Create a new transparent layer and drag it to the bottom of the layers stack
6. Select white as the foreground colour in the toolbar, and do *Edit > Fill with FG color*. This will fill the selection with white. This layer will act as a base fill layer.
7. Do *Select > None*
8. Select the top layer in the layers panel
9. Do *Colors > Color to Alpha*, and click OK

Here's the result

[image]

Add a contrasting fill underneath, and zoom in. There should be no problematic pixel outline. Here's part of the image at 100% zoom

[image]

Note: If you think the logo has become too light here, you can duplicate the color to alpha layer, and adjust it's opacity to adjust the lightness/darkness.

Comment: Color-to-alpha no longer works perfectly in 2.10 as it did in 2.8. Bucket-filling with `Color erase` is a better way in 2.10 (it can also be used by painting a layer above, and setting the layer to `Color erase`).

Comment: @xendoid, I used this in 2.10 - seems to work fine. The result is pretty good IMHO

Comment: This still uses the Wand tool. I was thinking about something within the Layers tab, like different order of the black/white image layers and/or other mode than "difference". I initially though than transparency could be recovered in an "automated" way (rather than guessing the Wand threshold+Grow selection values) since there are two sources (and I only need the triangle logo anyway).

If I understand, the transparent layer will act as a mask to know which pixels should not become transparent.

Comment: @myself600 - there's nothing automatic that can do what you want. Sorry.  Not even Photoshop can do this perfectly to be honest. It's going to need some tweaking, to get the best results.  The difference method is practically useless for most background removal jobs anyway. Hardly ever a good idea.